# Book about summable families

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation

after studying summable series, I know that there exists the concept of summable families. There is any book where I can find the proof of the basic properties of summable families?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Summable families in what sense?  Something like $$\sum_{j \in J} a_j$$where $J$ is uncountable?  Why would there be a book on that?  At most there would be a few remarks within a textbook where the countable case is considered more fully.  One such is Exercise 6 S (p. 214) in

*Kelley, John L.*, General topology, The University Series in Higher Mathematics. New York: D. van Nostrand Co., Inc. 298 p., illustr. (1955). [ZBL0066.16604](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0066.16604).